# Gerar relatório no Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, relatório, microsoft-azure

Preciso gerar relatórios em uma aplicação MVC que será hospedada no Azure e fiquei sabendo através desse tutorial: [Utilizando o Report Viewer no ASP.NET MVC](http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2016/02/10/utilizando-o-report-viewer-no-asp-net-mvc/) que é necessário contratar uma Maquina Virtual para o reporter viwer funcionar. Pelo o que vejo nesse link  [Veja o que você pode fazer com o Azure gratuitamente](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/free/pricing-offers/) a opção gratuita do Azure não contempla a MV.
Existe uma outra opção de `gerador de relatório similar` ao `Report Viwer` que não precise contratar um MV ?

Answer (score 3):

Dê uma olhada no [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pt-br/)
da Microsoft. Estou conhecendo ele agora e até o momento estou impressionado com o que ele pode fazer.

[Tutorial aqui](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pt-br/guided-learning)

Espero que te ajude.

Comment: eu dei uma olhada por cima e vi que é um material muito rico mesmo e com muitos recursos excelentes!,  porém eu estava pensando em alguma ferramenta free e estou pesquisando o `Rotativa` https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa e o `PagedList` https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/ , estou vendo esse material http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-gerar-relatorios-no-asp-net-mvc/33921 que inicialmente seria uma boa, porém terei que exibir gráficos e essas não atende.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o Power BI Embedded para gerar os relatórios dentro da sua aplicação. Este é um recurso do azure, que é gratuito até 100 sessões/mês. Depois é cobrado U$5,00 para cada 100 sessões. 
Caso essa solução te atenda, recomendo que veja as restrições no link (https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/)